# Check how much of a circle is colliding with another circle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Started working on my [Agar.io](https://jsfiddle.net/khanfused/0sk4hxa2/17/) clone again. Basic collision detection between two circles is easy (distance < radii = collision). However, Agar's collision detection is a bit more complex. It seems like it detects how much of circle A encompasses circle B, but because it's not open-source, I can't figure out how they did it. I saw this [Agar clone](https://github.com/huytd/agar.io-clone) on GitHub, but it would seem they took the easier route and just did regular collision detection.

This is how I'm doing it right now.

```
collision: function(circle) {
    var xx = circle.x - this.x;
    var yy = circle.y - this.y;
    var distance = Math.sqrt(xx * xx + yy * yy);
    return distance < this.radius + circle.radius;
},
```

How would I check how much of a circle is inside of another circle?

Comment: by encompass do you mean how much of the circumference or how much area? Either way, some high school level maths is all you need - http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html

Comment: Area, not circumference.

Comment: that's good, because the math I linked to shows how to do area

Comment: Just to be sure, uh, you're talking about #16, right?

Comment: It's probably a little more complex than that - seeing as the maths on that page has both circles on y=0 and one circle on x=0 ... some mathematical transforms will need to be performed

Comment: Hm. I tried `Math.abs(this.radius + circle.radius) - distance > this.radius / 2` and it kinda works... sometimes...

Comment: Find the 2 intersection points of the circles and then calculate the area of each circle segments like this: `(radius*radius)/2 * (Math.PI/180*centralAngle-Math.sin(centralAngle))`

Comment: Uh... where centralAngle = ?

Comment: I've added an answer explaining the process. Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 4):

**You can calculate the area of intersection between 2 circles by adding the areas of the 2 intersecting circle sections:**

[image]

1. Calculate the 2 points where the circles intersect.

[image]

2. Calculate the central angle formed by the intersecting wedge. The central angle is formed by connecting one intersecting point to the circle centerpoint to the other intersecting point.

[image]

3. Calculate the area of a circle section. You can calculate the area of a circle section by first calculating the area of the wedge and then subtracting the area of the wedge's non-arc triangle.

[image]minus[image]equals[image]

4. Repeat for both circles and add both section areas to get the total area of the intersection of 2 circles.

[image]

**Example code and a Demo**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }


// define 2 circles
var c1={x:100,y:100,r:100};
var c2={x:200,y:200,r:150};

// get points where 2 circles' perimeters intersect 
var pts=intersection(c1.x,c1.y,c1.r,c2.x,c2.y,c2.r);

// get the angle formed by one intersection point
// and the circle's centerpoint
// and the other intersection point
var centralAngle1=centralAngle({x:pts.x1,y:pts.y1},{x:c1.x,y:c1.y},{x:pts.x2,y:pts.y2});
var centralAngle2=centralAngle({x:pts.x1,y:pts.y1},{x:c2.x,y:c2.y},{x:pts.x2,y:pts.y2});

// calculate the area of the two circle sectors
var sector1area=parseInt(sectorArea(c1.r,centralAngle1));
var sector2area=parseInt(sectorArea(c2.r,centralAngle2));

draw();


function draw(){
  // stroke circles
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(c1.x,c1.y,c1.r,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(c2.x,c2.y,c2.r,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  // intersecting chord
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(pts.x1,pts.y1);
  ctx.lineTo(pts.x2,pts.y2);
  ctx.stroke();
  // intersection points 
  ctx.fillStyle='red';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(pts.x1,pts.y1,5,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(pts.x2,pts.y2,5,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.fillStyle='black';
  // sector labels
  ctx.fillText('sector2',100,100);
  ctx.fillText('sector1',135,135);
  // report sector areas
  ctx.fillText(sector2area,100,112);
  ctx.fillText(sector1area+'px',135,147);
  ctx.fillText('px',100,124);
  //
  ctx.fillText('circle#1',c1.x-35,c1.y-35);
  ctx.fillText('circle#2',c2.x,c2.y);
}

// calc area of circle section
function sectorArea(radius,radianSweep){
  var PI=Math.PI;
  var PI2=PI*2;
  // area of wedge with specified sweep angle
  var wedgeArea=(PI*radius*radius)*radianSweep/PI2;
  // area of triangle formed by 2 radii & radianSweep 
  // == side angle side method
  var triangleArea=0.50*radius*radius*Math.sin(radianSweep);
  // subtract triangle area from wedge area
  // leaving the sector area
  return(wedgeArea-triangleArea);
}

// return angle between 3 points
function centralAngle(p0,p1,p2) {
  var dx1=p1.x-p0.x;
  var dy1=p1.y-p0.y;
  var dx2=p1.x-p2.x;
  var dy2=p1.y-p2.y;
  var dx3=p2.x-p0.x;
  var dy3=p2.y-p0.y;
  var a=dx1*dx1+dy1*dy1;
  var b=dx2*dx2+dy2*dy2;
  var c=dx3*dx3+dy3*dy3;
  return(Math.acos((a+b-c)/Math.sqrt(4*a*b)));
}


function centralAngleX(x1,y1,x2,y2){
  var dx=x2-x1;
  var dy=y2-y1;
  return(Math.abs(Math.atan2(dy,dx)));
}

function intersection(x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1) {
  var a, dx, dy, d, h, rx, ry;
  var x2, y2;
  /* dx and dy are the vertical and horizontal distances between
     * the circle centers.
     */
  dx = x1 - x0;
  dy = y1 - y0;
  /* Determine the straight-line distance between the centers. */
  d = Math.sqrt((dy*dy) + (dx*dx));
  /* Check for solvability. */
  if (d > (r0 + r1)) {
    /* no solution. circles do not intersect. */
    return false;
  }
  if (d < Math.abs(r0 - r1)) {
    /* no solution. one circle is contained in the other */
    return false;
  }
  /* 'point 2' is the point where the line through the circle
     * intersection points crosses the line between the circle
     * centers.  
     */
  /* Determine the distance from point 0 to point 2. */
  a = ((r0*r0) - (r1*r1) + (d*d)) / (2.0 * d) ;
  /* Determine the coordinates of point 2. */
  x2 = x0 + (dx * a/d);
  y2 = y0 + (dy * a/d);
  /* Determine the distance from point 2 to either of the
     * intersection points.
     */
  h = Math.sqrt((r0*r0) - (a*a));
  /* Now determine the offsets of the intersection points from
     * point 2.
     */
  rx = -dy * (h/d);
  ry = dx * (h/d);
  /* Determine the absolute intersection points. */
  var xi = x2 + rx;
  var xi_prime = x2 - rx;
  var yi = y2 + ry;
  var yi_prime = y2 - ry;
  return({x1:xi, y1:yi, x2:xi_prime, y2:yi_prime});
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
```

Comment: Hm. Why are the values so large?

Comment: @Raiden The values appear correct. The area of the intersection contains many pixels.

Comment: Yeah, but how I do get those to values I can work with?

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. You asked how to find "Check how much of a circle is colliding with another circle ... Area, not circumference."

Comment: Okay... but how do I use those?

Comment: *"How much of a circle is colliding with another circle?"* In the example: 4629 pixels + 10467 pixels - 192 common pixels on the line between the two sections = 14904 pixels of each circle are colliding with the other circle.

Comment: But I can't do anything with the pixels in calculations... how do I revert them back to values that are correctly scaled with the radii, etc?

Comment: **Sigh**...At this point I think you've asked the wrong question! You mention "area" and *area has a specific math meaning -- and I've calculated that area for you in my answer*. But ... Are you really trying to resolve the collision of 2 intersecting circles? If yes, check out [this post](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131424/pool_hall_lessons_fast_accurate_.php?page=1) to get you started.